# Let $A_n=(x_n-1,x_n+1)$. Does exist $\lim_n\sup A_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be some enumeration of the rational numbers $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R$ and define $A_n=(x_n-1,x_n+1)$. Does exist $\lim_\limits n\sup A_n$ and $\lim_\limits n\inf A_n$?

I've understand $\lim\limits_n\sup X_n$ as the set of elements of $X_n$ for an infinite values of $n$. In every $A_n$ exists an infinite number of rational numbers. By this intuition makes me think "If the limit exist, then we should have $\lim\sup A_n=\Bbb R$", is this correct ?

For make me understand better the problem, I've tried changing the problem looking for some equivalent sentence, but I have no ideia how to make progress on this.

Comment: what is the gcd of rational number?

Comment: @Exodd I assume $(a,b)$ refers to the open interval here, not to GCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To prove: $\limsup_{n}A_{n}=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Note that
$(x-1,x+1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite set, so there exists $k\geq n$
such that $x_{k}\in(x-1,x+1)$. Therefore $|x-x_{k}|<1$ and it implies
that $x\in(x_{k}-1,x_{k}+1)$. Hence, $x\in\cup_{k\geq n}A_{k}$.
Lastly, since $n$ is arbitrary, we have $x\in\cap_{n}\cup_{k\geq n}A_{k}=\limsup_{n}A_{n}$.
It follows that $\limsup_{n}A_{n}=\mathbb{R}$.

---

2. To prove: $\liminf A_{n}=\emptyset$.

Prove by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $x\in\liminf A_{n}$.
Then, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in\cap_{k\geq n}A_{k}$.
That is, $|x_{k}-x|<1$ for all $k\geq n$. In another word, $x_{k}\in(x-1,x+1)$
for all $k\geq n$. Now, $\mathbb{Q}\setminus(x-1,x+1)\subseteq\{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$,
which is a contradiction because $\mathbb{Q}\setminus(x-1,x+1)$ is
an infinite set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\lim_\limits n\sup A_n = \cap_{n \geq 1} \cup_{k \geq n} A_k$$

Show that for each $n \geq 1$ you have
$$ \cup_{k \geq n} A_k = \mathbb R$$

For the other

$$\lim_\limits n\inf A_n = \cup_{n \geq 1} \cap_{k \geq n} A_k$$

Show that for each $n \geq 1$ you have
$$ \cap_{k \geq n} A_k = \emptyset$$

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but did you mean $\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k=\Bbb R$ and $\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k=\emptyset$ for each $n\geq1$ ?

Comment: @Souza Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is valid, but it is not applied correctly.

If you want to prove that the limsup is $\mathbb R$, then you must consider any $y\in \mathbb R$ and prove that it is contained frequently in $n$ into $A_n$.

Now, since $(y-1,y+1)$ contains an infinite number of rationals, then the thesis follows.